# Present ViewController from its title

Tags: swift, xcode

**Background**

I am developing an application which contains a top nav bar with an icon that allows to go back to the main `ViewController`.

As there as several `ViewController`s, I don't want to duplicate the segue on each `ViewController`. I would prefer to create a custom class for the top nav bar and be able to programmatically present the main `ViewController`. I found that I could maybe call `present(viewControllerToPresent:animated:completion)`

**Questions**

- Is this the right way to do it?
- How do I access the controller I need to pass to this function?
- Is there a method which allows to get the controller from its title?

Also, as the main ViewController has already been instantiated when the application started, do I need to instantiate a new one or can I get a reference to the existing one?

Answer (score 1):

So if I get this correct you click mainVC->firstVC->secondVC->nthVC and then you'd want to go directly back to mainVC ? View controllers are stacked so what I'd do is just dismiss all those view controllers that are above mainVC.

Comment: +1, that works. I would like to be able to redirect the user to another ViewController with another button on the nav bar. For this use case, dismissing does not work. Do you know a solution?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Presenting the viewController aint an option i suppose?
Then i would suggest checking for it in the stack:
for vc in (navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
            if vc is MainMenuController {
                break
            } else {
                if navigationController?.viewControllers.count == 1 {
                    present(your_viewcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }

Comment: @Vollan I tried to present the ViewController but do not know how to get a reference to it. As stated in the question, I found that I could call `present(viewControllerToPresent:animated:completion)` but how to get a reference to the target ViewController?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle ah, sorry missed that:
`let viewContoller = YourViewController()` and then
`present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: @Vollan Isn't it bad to instantiate a new one each time I navigate to it? I thought I could "get or create" the ViewController

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Indeed it is, check the for-loop i wrote couple of comments up.
It basically goes through all your viewControllers and is closing them and if you havn't found the one you're searching for when only having 1 left, you will open a new one (the one you search for)

Or i think you can use `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` right after the present and you will close down the previous viewcontroller when moving on to the next one